# Manifest in android studio does not work

Tags: android, xml

I have some problems with manifest in android java programming. I do not know how to fix it. Any help is appreciated.

It says The processing instructions goal match........ is not allowed. And in the beginning: Serious: null = SERIOUS : null – .

And: Error:Cannot read packageName from C:\Users\arnpet\AndroidStudioProjects\UltimateHogskoleprovet\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

Here is the manifext file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.arnpet.ultimatehogskoleprovet" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".pageBeforeAction"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_page_before_action" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".toppLista"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_topp_lista" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".information"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_information" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".GameAction"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_game_action" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".QuestionBox"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_question_box" >
    </activity>


</application>
```

Comment: Package name.. does it ring a bell??

Comment: When I created a new project this was the output of manifest in the beginning. And the manifest ends with </manifest>, but there it works as normal. What is the problem

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.arnpet.ultimatehogskoleprovet"
    android:versionCode="229"
    android:versionName="2.2.9"

 >

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your AndroidManifest.xml is malformed. Its missing the opening & closing  tags.

Try to create a new project and look at its AndroidManifest.xml.

The beginning of an Android Manifest usually looks like:

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xyz"
    android:versionCode="229"
    android:versionName="2.2.9" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-permission ... />
<application>...</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `<manifest>` tag set attribute `package = "[your package]"`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Is this the whole *AndroidManifest.xml*? Because you missing the `manifest` tag. In this tag, there is a attribute `package` defining the packagename of your app.

See the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#filec) for more information and example of a complete manifest file.